# Normal and tangent to curve in openCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Is there a robust method for finding the tangent and the normal to a drawn curve in openCV? In the image, I drawed some normal vectors to the curve. The input is just some curves drawed.

[image]

Comment: You should give us examples of your code, what you did try and what you got.

Comment: Fit a straight line to each local part of the curve.

Comment: Or, if the curve has enough thickness, e.g. response value of Sobel Filter may be able to use (as an approx).

Comment: @fana, that is the thing, I tried Sobel Filter but it didn't work. Why does the curve need to be thick in order to use Sobel Filter?

Comment: Such a filter assumes that its center lies on the boundary between two regions with different pixel values. So, the response value is unreliable when there are three or more regions within the range.
Therefore, Here, if the thickness is very thin relative to the size of the filter, meaning of the calculation may become to unknown.

Comment: For your sample image, it looks like that generic 3x3 sobel filter can be used. (larger, e.g. 5x5 may be able to be used too). Response values of 2 directional filters (x-dir and y-dir) at the edge position can be use as the vector (as the normal or tangent directional vector).